# How to change a query value on an api call based on Redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I have this issue that i do not know how to figure it out, this action.js is doing an api call to my app from weatherApi, what I need is make a button to change cityName value to another as 'madrid' for example, another button to change lang value. How could i do it from app.js or can I get it done on the same file action.js

```
const appid = 'randomapi';
const cityName = 'london';
const lang  = 'en';
export const fetchData = () => {
    
    return (dispatch) => {
        return fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&lang=${lang}&appid=${appid}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => dispatch(
                { type: "FetchData", data: json }))
            .catch(err => dispatch(
                { type: "ERROR",msg: "Unable to fetch data" }))
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are the parameters coming from?

Comment: hello, this is the issue i need those parameters coming from a button replacion value on those const appid cityname and lang. I just do not figure it out . How to make buttons to make this action

Comment: You pass them along as arguments for the thunk `fetchData`.